# First time using LTSpice

Tags: ltspice

It's my first time using LTSpice that was required for us to use but our prof didn't know that most of us haven't used ltspice yet. I already have done the schematic diagram but i dont know how to input the parameters, can someone pls help me? [image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Right-click on the component. Eventually even Ctrl-Right-click. Yeah, LTspice isn't very intuitive, but once you get used to it, is is very efficient to get things done.

Comment: @dim And yet, this is explained in the help, in the introduction. Admittedly, it's one of the more terse help files, but it is explained, and a simple look could save you a ton of headaches later on.

Answer (score 1):

Right-Click on the `NMOS4` symbol once placed on the schematic and enter the width and length there. If you have additional parameters, you're better off adding your own `.model` card, something like this:

```
.model NMOStest NMOS L=<length> W=<width> Vto=<Vto> ...
```

where `NMOStest` is the name you'll be giving to your NMOS. You can see more details about possible parameters in the help (`LTspice > Circuit Elements > M`). It's quite spartan, but it does help. As for the rest of the calculations, I think that's up to you.

Comment: Thank you! but how do i put the parameters for K' and K'W/L? :/

Comment: @Roberto I gave you a direction to read about the MOSFET in LTspice, and about its parameters. If you'll try a bit, you'll spot there, in the table, a certain parameter `Kp` [A/V<sup>2</sup>], one `lambda` [1/V], and maybe others, as well (hint: V<sub>t0</sub> is `Vto`, the one I deliberately mentioned in the control card example).